Is there a link between a multivariate VAR specification and the bivariate ones arising when combining the variables in groups of two?
Consider $x_t=(x_t^1,x_t^2,x_t^3)$ and a simple Vector Autoregression (VAR) of order one for its dynamics, given by
$$
x_t=\Phi x_{t-1}+\epsilon_t,
$$
where $\phi\in\mathbb{R}^{3x3}$ satisfies the invertibility condition (if desired).
Is there any connection between the matrix $\Phi$ and the matrices arising from the VARs specified in terms of two variables at a time from $x_t$, $x_t^{(1,2)}=(x_t^1,x_t^2),\ x_t^{(1,3)}=(x_t^1,x_t^3),\ \text{and}\ x_t^{(2,3)}=(x_t^2,x_t^3)$?
$$
x_t^{(1,2)}=A x_{t-1}^{(1,2)}+\epsilon_t^{(1,2)}, \\
x_t^{(1,3)}=B x_{t-1}^{(1,3)}+\epsilon_t^{(1,3)}, \\
x_t^{(2,3)}=C x_{t-1}^{(2,3)}+\epsilon_t^{(2,3)}
$$
What if the errors are orthogonal $E[\epsilon_t\epsilon_t']=I$, where $I\in\text{diag} (1)$ is the identity matrix? Or if they are not orthogonal, but an orthogonal version could be obtained leveraging their form $\epsilon_t=\Sigma u_t$, where $E[u_t u_t']=I$?
What about a similar reasoning in terms of their moving average (MA) representation (obviously assuming invertibility),
$$
x_t=\Theta(L)\epsilon_t
$$
where $\Theta(L)=(I-\Phi L)^{-1}$, or
$$
x_t=\Xi(L) u_t
$$
where $\Xi(L)=\Theta(L)\Sigma$ and $E[u_t u_t']=I$?
I am trying to recover $\Xi(L)$ from $\Xi(L)^{(1,2)}$, $\Xi(L)^{(1,3)}$, and $\Xi(L)^{(2,3)}$ arising when considering MA representations of the bivariate VARs obtained by combining the elements of $x_t$, which in my case are known.
